# Char* not retaining text inside my class - initialization constructor problem?

Tags: c++

I have the following class (I've trimmed irrelevant stuff):

```
class Example
{
    private:
        char* name;
        int value[4];
        int numVals;
    public:
        Example();
        Example(char name[], int numVals, int, int, int, int);
        ~Example();
};
```

And here is the initialization constructor:

```
Example::Example(char na[], int vals, int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4)
{
    name = new char[strlen(na)+1];
    strcpy(name, na);
    numVals = vals;
    value[0] = v1;
    value[1] = v2;
    value[2] = v3;
    value[3] = v4;
    // cout << name; // this DOES print out the correct text

}
```

In my main(), I have an array of Example class, `Example myArray[numRecs]`. I then have a loop that uses the initialization constructor to fill the array:

```
myArray[i] = Example(name, numVals, v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3]);
```

Everything works as expected, however the `name` does not retain the characters I put into it. I checked using cout what the value is when it is passed into the constructor, and it was correct! However when I use my Example::Print(), it spits out a random character (the same character for each instance of Example).

Here is the Example::Print()

```
void Example::Print()
{
    int total, avg;
    total = avg = 0;

    cout << left << setw(20) << name << '\t';

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        if(i<numVals){
            cout << left << setw(8) << value[i];
            total += value[i];
        } else
            cout << left << setw(8) << " ";
    }
    avg = total/numVals;
    cout << left << setw(8) << total <<
        left << setw(8) << avg << endl;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Oh and also, this is for an assignment. We have been told to keep the name field as a char pointer, not a string. I am confused as to what I should be using for the init constructor (char* name  or  char name[]  or.. is there a difference?)

EDIT: Here is the destructor and default constructor. I do not have a copy constructor yet as the assignment does not call for it and it is not used. I'll go ahead and make one for completeness anyway.

```
Example::~Example()
{
    delete [] name;
}

Example::Example()
{
    numVals = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        value[i] = -1;

}
```

Comment: There is no difference between `char *name` and `char name[]` **in a formal parameter list**. They are quite different as `extern` declarations, for example.

Comment: @Henning thanks, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run your program through a memory debugger to witness the nightmare you've created!

You are using manual memory management in your class, yet you forgot to obey the Rule of Three: You didn't implement the copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor! Thus the temporary does allocate memory, copies *the pointer* (shallowly), and then probably invalidates the memory when it goes out of scope.

The immediate "fix my code" answer is that you have to implement a proper assignment operator and copy constructor to make a deep copy of the char array.

The "this is C++" answer is not to use pointers, `new` and arrays, and instead `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks Kerrek, looks like I have forgotten my memory management. I thought I had indeed done a full copy (created memory with `name = new char[strlen(na)+1]` and then copied with `strcpy(name, na)`. I must have missed something.

Comment: @Paul he means when you assign one of your `Example` objects to another one or use the copy constructor. In those cases, the new object gets a copy of the _pointer_, not its own copy of the data. Then when the original goes out of scope, it deallocates the memory that the others were pointing to. Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

Comment: Paul: Why why why won't you consider using `std::string`?

Comment: @Kerrek: Assignment restriction I'm afraid. I realised that the line `myArray[i] = Example(name, numVals, v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3]);` was actually calling the assignment operator (that did not yet exist). I though that would use the initialization constructor, but I was incorrect. I couldnt figure out how to make it use the init constructor, so I just made a temp Example class using the init constructor, then copied it into MyArray of Examples using the assignment operator I made.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the homework tag. OK. There's no such thin as an "initialization constructor" -- you are thinking of *initialization* `T x = y;`, which uses the copy constructor. But in your case the target object already exists, and you're calling the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be to store pointers to the Examples in the array instead of the actual objects. This way, you don't have to deal with copying (which you haven't implemented).